# Shield UI Pie chart hierarchical functionality

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, shieldui

I have a question regarding ShieldUI pie chart. What I need is to provide following functionality on a web page. Initially a pie chart will represent some data. When user clicks on a slice

I need that slice’s compound data to be broken down taking up the whole chart. Let’s give an example with sales volumes. Initially we have the sales volumes for all the four quarters of the year. Than the user clicks on the first quarter slice. And it divides into let’s say months, or weeks. All that data I need to take up the whole chart. In other words in need some sort of multi dimensional data zooming.

I searched for some sort of hierarchical pie charts, but what they do is to show all the data a once, which is not quite I really need.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you need it might be not the chart itself, but the relation of multiple charts that provide the functionality you want. 
You may take a look at this answer:

[Linking graphs of two Shield UI Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329374/linking-graphs-of-two-shield-ui-charts)

The number of related and subordinate charts will be equal to the data depth you have. For instance if you have 3 levels- quarters, weeks and days, you will have 3 related chart. The users will first click on the quarter slice, than on the week.

You could even more fully match the functional behavior needed by using one container for rendering all the charts to. There is however one disadvantage that you will need a button or a link to provide users the possibility to return to the top level.